# Can't display leaflet.js map in Vue component

Tags: leaflet, vue.js

I am getting error:

Here is my code:

```
var guestContent = Vue.extend({
      template: `
   <div>
    test
   </div>  
          `,
        data: function ()  
            {
              return {
                map: false
              }
            },
          ready: function()
          { 
            this.map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
          },
          methods: 
          { 

          }

        }
        );

var userContent = Vue.extend({
      template: `
              <p>SOME USER CONTENT TEST</p>
          `
        });

var adminContent = Vue.extend({
      template: `
        <p>ADMIN CONTENT TEST</p>

        <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

          `
        });
```

I am getting next error: `Map container not found`.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM is not ready when you try to create the map. Wrap it with this.$nextTick().

```
ready: function() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You created 3 different components: guestContent, userContent, adminContent. 
But you load map only in guestContent which don't has tag with id="map". You need to add map container to template.

```
    var guestContent = Vue.extend({
      template: `
   <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
          `,
        data: function ()  
            {
              return {
                map: false
              }
            },
          ready: function()
          { 
            this.map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
          },
          methods: 
          { 

          }

        }
        );

Vue.component('guest-content', guestContent)
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/3dqeuoqL/